# Specify shipping at order creation - Stripe

Tags: stripe-payments

I have a small shop application where there will only be 3 types of possible postage options depending on the quantity of items selected. If its less than 3 items its x amount, more than 2 but less than 5 x amount, and 5 or more x amount.

I want to be able to specify this at the point of purchase. My POST request looks like this:

```
router.post('/pay', (req, res) => {

    var totalItems = 1;
    var itemPrice = 495
    var shipping;

    if (totalItems < 2) {
        shipping = 150
    } else if (totalItems > 2 && totalItems < 5) {
        shipping = 250
    } else {
        shipping = 350
    }

    const token = req.body.stripeToken;

    const charge = stripe.charges.create({
        amount: totalItems * itemPrice,
        currency: 'gbp',
        description: 'Example charge',
        source: token
    });

    const order = stripe.orders.create({
        currency: 'gbp',
        email: 'test@me.com',
        items: [
          {
            type: 'sku',
            parent: 'sku_EMfaxNyIExLS8I',
            quantity: totalItems,
          },
          {
            type: "shipping",
            amount: shipping,
            currency: "gbp",
            description: "Shipping",
            parent: "shipping",
            quantity: 1,
          }
        ],
        shipping: {
          name: 'George',
          address: {
            line1: '1234 Main Street',
            city: 'San Francisco',
            state: 'CA',
            postal_code: '94111',
            country: 'US',
          },
        },

    });

})
```

But when I try and submit the payment, I get the following error:

```
Unhandled rejection Error: Items of type `shipping` are not supported at order creation.
```

I would really like to be able to just specify the shipping at this level, as I do not understand the Stripe documentation about returning 200 status codes etc. found [here](https://stripe.com/docs/orders/dynamic-shipping-taxes). I'm not too familiar with server side coding.

If anyone could assist I would greatly appreciate it.

Many thanks,

G

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not possible to define the shipping information on an order directly at the time it's created — you do instead need to use the callback [approach](https://stripe.com/docs/orders/dynamic-shipping-taxes) you mentioned where Stripe sends the order details to either a third-party or a custom server of yours, to calculate the shipping on the order.

In this case I'd recommend not using an Order object here, and just go with creating a charge directly using `stripe.charges.create` and calculating the up-front amount for that charge in your code.